# Get value of PHP Object with Backslashes from Unsplash PHP Wrapper

Tags: php

I'm trying to make friends with Unsplash's PHP API. But how do I get the value out of the object?

```php
$search = Unsplash\Search::photos($search, $page, $per_page, $orientation);
var_dump($search);
```

**Result**

```
Unsplash\PageResult Object
(
    [resultClassName:Unsplash\PageResult:private] => Unsplash\Photo
    [total:Unsplash\PageResult:private] => 1052
    [totalPages:Unsplash\PageResult:private] => 351
)
```

Normally I would do the following right?

```php
<?php echo $search->total; ?>
```

But I can't get it to work. Is it cause of the Backslashes? Or is it a namespace or similar? Or how can I loop through it? Sorry for the newbie questions in PHP.

Ideally, I would like to loop through the object. Or does it make sense to convert this into an array beforehand?

Comment: Use the `get*` Methods as shown here, https://github.com/unsplash/unsplash-php/blob/master/src/PageResult.php e.g `$search->getTotal()`

Comment: And `$search->total` can not work here, because all properties in the class are `private` not `public`

Comment: The `get*` Methods working perfect!! Thanks so so much!